# Unable to import 'plotly.graph_objects' pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, django, plotly

i am trying to create a guage chart using plotly and that is indeed possible using the following code snippet

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number",
    value = 270,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    title = {'text': "Speed"}))

fig.show()
```

well that's not the problem, the problem is that i can't import plotly although it is installed `pip install --upgrade plotly Requirement already up-to-date: plotly in c:\users\nader\desktop\guage\env\lib\site-packages (4.9.0) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: retrying>=1.3.3 in c:\users\nader\desktop\guage\env\lib\site-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in c:\users\nader\desktop\guage\env\lib\site-packages (from plotly) (1.15.0)` well the error occurs here

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

the error i get is the following `Unable to import 'plotly.graph_objects'pylint(import-error)`

Any Help is appreciated, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the version of Plotly.

```
pip uninstall plotly
pip install plotly==3.10.0
```